# How to use Focus Magnification on Sony A7 with adapted lenses?

Tags: sony, manual-focus, lens-adapter

When I bought the Sony A7 I put a Kiwi adapter on it and tried using my old 24mm and 28-200 and both Focus Peaking and Focus Zoom still worked. Today with that same adapter I was looking at a Nikon 50 1.4 AIS. Peaking came on but the Focus Magnifier didn't. Should all Lenses activate the Focus Magnifier or how would I know which ones will and won't?

Comment: That's odd. The focus magnifier on my NEX-6 always activates when I press the button no matter what lens is on it, and I use a lot of old glass. Are you sure it's the lens causing this?

Comment: Which button are you using? I think they are assignable on the A7, and if you assign it to one button it acts different than on another. Also do you have it set to "ignore if lens is missing" in the settings menu?

Comment: @Beartech generally it just comes on when focusing. I'm wondering if I'm remembering incorrectly about it coming on with my old 24mm because reading online says it can work but needs to be programmed to come on via button. And no I'm not sure if it was the lens, I didn't purchase it or the adapter yet until I could investigate more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, guess I was mistaken because Focus Peaking works by default but the Focus Magnification doesn't work with adapters.

However, I found online a workaround and just set it up to test - worked perfectly.

Full detailed instructions head to Silvermac at http://www.silvermac.com/2015/07/29/sony-a7-ii-using-mf-assist-with-the-lens-adapters/

Basically, turn Focus Magnification on and the time to No Limit. Then go to Custom Buttons and choose one to use for it. Hit that button once then the Center Button and you're in business. Works great.